# Apple Distribution certificates are not working in macOS 10.14.6 with Xcode 11.3.1

Tags: ios, xcode, provisioning-profile, tvos, code-signing-certificate

I'm trying to create ad-hoc distributions of some iOS and tvOS apps on a system running macOS 10.14.6 with Xcode 11.3.1. The process I've been using for this has been working for years, but since my yearly Apple Distribution certificate just expired, I created a new one and tried to resign and reinstall all of my apps.

However, for some reason now it's not working. If I open up Keychain Access, it reports that the certificate I just had Xcode generate is not trusted. If I list my Apple dev account's certificates in Xcode's preferences under Accounts / Manage Certificates, it list the certificate but does so in a way that indicates something is wrong:

[image: bad certificate list]

Note that these are two entries listed for the same certificate. Finally, if I try to export any of my apps for ad-hoc distribution, Xcode doesn't report any errors but the apps just fail to launch on an iOS or tvOS device.

All of the device I'm working with are running older versions of iOS / tvOS that ought to work with Xcode 11.3.1. Has Apple changed something about the certificate generation process so that Xcode 11.3.1 is no longer able to generate valid certificates? Is there anything I can do to get this process working on my Mojave system?

(Please note that updating my system past Mojave is not an option, so I can't use newer versions of Xcode.)

Comment: You only get the Not in Keychain status when the certificate is not created on this specific machine. Did you create the certificate on this machine you are running the project on?

Comment: You should have those devices udids in the certificate right?

Comment: @hasan The certificate was created on that machine. The screenshot is showing that Xcode is listing the same certificate twice, once reporting that it's not installed, and the other reporting that it *is* installed but my name is missing from it for some reason. All of my devices are included in the provisioning profiles I'm using to sign the apps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Even though it still displays incorrectly in Xcode 11.3.1, the issue was that I had not installed the new Apple Worldwide Developer Relations Intermediate Certificate. Once I downloaded from [here](https://developer.apple.com/support/expiration/) and installed it, I could use my Apple Distribution certificate again.